# Part of loop doesn't run

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My goal was for script to first look if element is on that page, if not open up closed sub categories and close opened ones on page, after opening them search again for that element and if element is still not there, click on next page and repeat the proccess until element is found and click on it, but the **except** part of loop doesn't run only **try** and after that nothing happens, no errors.

```
def onecolumn():
    try:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[child::span[text()='{odds}'] and span[text()='{howtobet}']]"))).click()
    except:
        pass
def separatecolumn():
    try:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[@class='srb-ParticipantLabel gl-Market_General-cn1 ' and contains(., '{odds}')]/following::span[text() ='{howtobet}']"))).click()
    except:
        pass

def subcategoryfunction():
    subcategories = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gl-MarketGroupButton_Text '))))
    subcategorylist = []

    for subcategory in subcategories:
        text = subcategory.text
        subcategorylist.append(text)
        print(text)

    time.sleep(3)

    subcategorylist2 = subcategorylist

    time.sleep(3)

    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(5)

    for i in range(0, len(subcategorylist2)):
        subcategoryindex = subcategorylist2[i]
        try:
            onecolumn() or separatecolumn()
            break
        except:
            ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException,)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 2, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[text() ='{subcategoryindex}']"))).click()

############Main###################
categories = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.sph-MarketGroupNavBarButton '))))
categorylist = []

for category in categories:
    text = category.text
    categorylist.append(text)
    print(text)

time.sleep(1)

categorylist2 = categorylist

driver.refresh()
time.sleep(10)

for i in range(1, len(categorylist2)):
    categoryindex = categorylist2[i]
    try:
        subcategoryfunction()
        break
    except:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException,)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 2, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[text() ='{categoryindex}']"))).click()
```

Comment: Without full code we cannot help

Comment: I managed to fix it yesterday, thanks away